# Unable to install ANY package (Unable to locate package)

Tags: software-installation, 19.10

Every time I try to install something, it just tells me it's unable to locate the package, running ubuntu on an Asus Zenbook pro UX550GE if that helps.

Things I have already done:

- Added right repository
- sudo apt-get clean; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -f install
- touch /etc/apt/sources.list
- Changed download server

I'm trying to install Ukuu to update the kernel, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[For uuku you have to pay since uuku version 19.01](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/01/ubuntu-kernel-update-utility-ukuu-moves.html)

uuku moves to a licence model. [More info from dev](https://teejeetech.in/2019/01/20/ukuu-v19-01/)